# Unable to deploy shiny app on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am running shiny example in https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/blob/master/guide/guide.md .

It works fine on my computer, but when i try to deploy on shiny server using RStudio, R console says:

> Application successfully deployed to
>   http://epidemiologia-asppalermo.shinyapps.io/shinyprova"

On my browser I get:

> "ERROR: object 'dataset' not found".

In my working directory there are the following objects:
diamonds (dataframe) dataset (dataframe, same as diamonds) server.R ui.R .

I use R 3.1.0, RStudio 0.98.932 and windows 7, 32 bit, all my R packages are updated.

Anyone can tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: I have similar problem but the error is  `ERROR: object 'package' not found`. I have installed all the packages. I also see `Application successfully deployed` message. Where you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the original deployment but perhaps you've declared diamonds to server.R but Ui.R is being asked to work with diamonds, instead of being fed from Server.R?