# Upload error in basic shiny app in shinyapps.io portal

Tags: r, shiny

A very simple shiny app with upload feature is working locally but not on shinyapps.io

Code :

```
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Upload file")
)
server <- function(input, output){

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Error occurring looks like this :

[image]

Link to shinyapps.io app : https://babai.shinyapps.io/stackO/

File to test on upload : http://www.mediafire.com/file/lh98smuid1mprxj/2018-05-20_02-00-10.mat/file

Have seen the following similar question ( [Error deploying shiny app that uses fileInput to upload data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825288/error-deploying-shiny-app-that-uses-fileinput-to-upload-data) ). But the solutions here does not work.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'accept = c(".mat")' to fileInput()?

Comment: Yes it does not work with accept also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the problem is caused by the specific encoding, which *shinyapps.io* doesn't recognize.
The function `fileInput()` tries to read the file content immediately in order to wrap it to `data.frame` with the predefined structure, and it fails when unknown encoding or corrupted file is provided. From the other hand, *shinyapps.io* has restricted possibilities to setup environment and encoding.

So, instead I'd suggest an alternative way of reading files with `readLines()` function. In the below example the user has to provide URL, which is then being read into a reactive variable. The variable then can be analyzed or processed. The test URL from your example does not cause errors.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Upload file"),              # FileInput (1)
  textOutput("content1"),                        # Text fragment (1)
  textInput("url", label = "Provide URL"),       # URL input (2)
  actionButton("download", label = "Read file"),
  textOutput("content2")                         # Text fragment (2)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  reactive_val <- reactiveValues()

  # File content
  output$content1 <- renderText({
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    x <- readLines(input$file$datapath, n = 5, skipNul =T)
    enc2native(x)
  })

  # Read URL content
  observeEvent(input$download, {
    my_file <- input$url
    if (is.null(my_file)) return(NULL)
    file_content <- readLines(my_file, n = 5, skipNul =T)
    reactive_val[["content"]] <- enc2native(file_content)
  }, ignoreInit = T)

  # URL file content
  output$content2 <- renderText({
    if (is.null(reactive_val[["content"]])) return(NULL)
    reactive_val[["content"]]
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```